# How to update content based on user actions [like the facebook wall]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

For my next application i would like to implement something that has a feature like the facebook wall but let me explain a bit. For those of you who used facebook you know that when somebody posts a message on your wall, and you are logged in to your account, you will get a notification immediately somewhere in the lower left corner. Lately they even pushed this a little bit further and if somebody comments on it the comments are updated as you visualize the page, it's like an instant chat.

My application will be developed in PHP, I will use Zend Framework to do it. I'm interested in the basic principle that makes the facebook wall behave like that (updates in real time). I know there is ajax involved but I can't really tell how is the javascript triggered when the user is doing something. Or even more, how to push back to a user some info that was added after he viewed the page. For example, let's say that a somebody adds me as a friend. I would like to see a notification saying "X has added you as a friend" if i am logged in. I hope you understand what I'm trying to do.
If you can tell me some basic ideas, maybe provide some links that have this information I would be very grateful.

Thank you for your time in reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to look at [comet](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start) , [reverse ajax](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/reverse-ajax/index.html) , [ajax polling](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Periodic_Refresh)

Answer (score 2):

1. If some event is triggered, then store the event on database (with ajax or without ajax).
2. You will be needing a script in server to check if some event has been triggered or not. This script should be able to check events that are stored in database.
3. You need to execute script in step 2 periodically. This can be acheived with with ajax (javascript or jquery) and a function `settimeout` (on javascript) to send ajax request to server periodically.
4. Changes are sent from server. So parse the response and update in page using javascipt and jquery.

So, it can be summarized as

1. Register an event (for one user)
2. Check the event (for other user)
3. Parse the response and update the page

There are several elegant ways to do this as answered by others.

The best would be the start the project and ask for help where ever stuck.

Comment: thank you for this, i didn't mark your answer as accepted because 3nigma provided some links of where i could find relative information. Though thank you for this, i will definitely remember your answer. Once i'll start the application i will come back here looking for help.

Comment: @user253530 sure! I am also very interested in developing some thing like that. If you start, let me know, maybe we could share some modules and maybe projects too

Answer (score 0):

It is only partially possible to keep an HTTP connection open, so the best option is probably to poll for changes. You can send a request each second to see if anything is changed since time 'x'. On each response you send along the server time. With the new request you send the time of the old request and the server can return any events that happened inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can read something about [AMQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMQP). You can send a message to recepients `inboxes` (after some actions in your system) and then read `inboxes` after start or with some time interval.