# displaying the result of a database query on change without refreshing the browser

Tags: php, database

i have a php script which writes data to a file every 5 seconds and have a second php script that opens the file and then queries a database based on the value in that file..

so to display the result of the query i need to run the php script on my browser..since the data in the file keeps changing,so the result of the query will also keep changing,but i can see the new result only when i refresh the browser..

I want a way in which i can see the new result of the query without refreshing the browser..
i am new to this so i hope i explained my problem to my best..waiting for a solution..thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use some AJAX function to retrieve the data, and then Javascript to update the browser. Check out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax for a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

this will automatically refresh the page for every 5secs

```
header( "refresh:5;url=page url link" );
```

Example :

header( "refresh:5;url=http://localhost/incedx.php" );

Comment: This is unecessary and expensive, Ajax is more suitable.

Comment: this is good but i want to refresh only the resut of the query on the page and not the entire page since doing that adds a time overhead of reloading the entire page..so i want to only refresh a part of the page and not the page fully..is there a way i could do that?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look at

[How to update content based on user actions [like the facebook wall]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142748/how-to-update-content-based-on-user-actions-like-the-facebook-wall/)

And you do not need to "i have a php script which writes data to a file every 5 seconds and have a second php script that opens the file and then queries a database based on the value in that file.."

Answer (score 0):

Write a JavaScript function and call it on load of page setInterval for that function so it is called after an interval of time in that function write ajax call to page which executes your query and return the values.

```
setinterval("test()" ,1000);
function test(){
//ajax call to php page
}
```

Comment: i tried doing this but i still have to click on 'reload' to get the updated value.where exactly do you have to put the setinterval function??while calling the test() function on load of page??

Comment: u can put at the bottom of page or in header <script type="text/javascript">setInterval("test()" , 1000)</script>